# convert object structure to array form

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I am using oreo fashion app and want some customization when i select variation a form appear in which we can add custom size i am using react native with wordpress api i want some guide please
I have an Object of maketomeasure like this

```
makeToMeasure:{
 shirtShoulder:"12",
 shirtChest:"13",
 shirtwaist:"14"
}
```

I want to change this Object to this Structure

```
 "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 33913,
            "name": "random",
            "product_id": 35493,
            "variation_id": 35509,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_class": "",
            "subtotal": "60",
            "subtotal_tax": "0",
            "total": "60",
            "total_tax": "0",
            "taxes": [],
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 322559,
                    "key": "pa_size",
                    "value": "make-to-measure"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322560,
                    "key": "pa_sleeves",
                    "value": "as-shown-in-picture"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322561,
                    "key": "pa_lowers",
                    "value": "as-shown-in-picture"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322562,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER",
                    "value": "15"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322563,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - SHIRT CHEST",
                    "value": "40"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322564,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - SHIRT WAIST",
                    "value": "36"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322565,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - SHIRT LENGTH",
                    "value": "36"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322566,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - SHIRT SLEEVE",
                    "value": "22"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322567,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - LOWER WAIST",
                    "value": "14.5"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322568,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - LOWER THIGH",
                    "value": "14"
                },
                {
                    "id": 322569,
                    "key": "maketomeasure - LOWER LENGTH",
                    "value": "40"
                }
            ],
            "sku": "SDS297",
            "price": 60
        },
```

I want to change meta_data format like above one

Comment: Do you want the `array` structure for the above `json object` , or do you need wordpress query to generate above?

Comment: i want same structure like meta data so i think i want json object

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of object destructuring to add a new item

```
const meta_data = line_items.meta_data;

const meta_data_changed = [...meta_data, makeToMeasure];

const line_items_added = [...line_items, meta_data: meta_data_changed];
```

You can further simplify it if you don't mind mutating the original array.

Comment: no i want maketomeasure object as meta_data why I map meta_data??

Comment: i dont want to change meta_data i just want to add more data to it

Comment: Do you want to convert `makeToMeasure` as an Array?

Comment: Ok I want to convert this make to measure array to above like example in my question where in meta_data i want add my object name and value in like key value

Comment: You can do:
`const makeToMeasureArray = [...makeToMeasure];`
This will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205206/discussion-between-imran-ali-and-kiran-jd).